# Linker error when compiling windows kernel mode driver x64

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, kmdf, wdm, wdf

I'm trying to compile the sysvad audio driver example found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad

Getting a linker error when compiling windows kernel mode driver x64

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf referenced in function _vsnwprintf_l`

Apparently my VC paths are jacked up, but i have tried many things, and cannot find where this lives.  I have tried adding `libucrt.lib` but that gives me a different error:

`warning LNK4257: object file was not compiled for kernel mode; the image might not run`

Everything compiles fine for Win32 version.