# unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf

Tags: printf, stdio, wdk, unresolved-external

I'm compiling a kernel mode driver that uses the Microsoft Dmf framework (DmfK.lib)

After the last Visual Studio update some strange linker errors appeared :

```
EmulationTargetPDO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf referenced in function _vsnwprintf_l
Utilities.lib(savedata.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf
DmfK.lib(DmfUtility.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf
EmulationTargetPDO.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf referenced in function _vsnprintf_l
DmfK.lib(DmfCore.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf
DmfK.lib(Dmf_CrashDump.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf_s referenced in function _vsprintf_s_l
```

Here's the software and kits versions I use (shown in VS "About" windows):

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version   16.10.0
- Windows SDK   10.0.19041.685
- Windows Driver Kit   10.0.19030.1000

The second strange thing is that I've downloaded and installed the WDK 10.0.19041.685 but VS still displays 10.0.19030.1000 ...

A similar problem can be found here : [Linker error when compiling windows kernel mode driver x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393271/linker-error-when-compiling-windows-kernel-mode-driver-x64) but it hasn't been solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set this define before including any headers:

```
#define _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE
```

or add it to the compiler's command line:

```
-D_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE
```

We (Microsoft driver team) are looking into this issue to see about removing the need for such a workaround.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the workaround is working !